# Vim - save buffer when foucs is lost from vim/nvim. Same as VSCode's "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange" setting

Tags: vim, neovim

VS-Code have a setting where we can save file when focus is lost.
In vim we have `autowriteall` which is good but it writes to all buffers.

Is there a way to do mimic `files.autoSave: onFocusChange` in vim for current buffer only ?

Comment: Note on `autowrite`: It will (silently) not work if `hidden` is on. `hidden` is off by default in `vim` but it is on by defaut in `neovim`. The `hidden` option is what allows  you to not unload a buffer when you're not seeing it anymore so if you want to work on multiple files it makes sense to have it on . Alas `autowrite` will not work with `hidden` because it only update a file when its buffer is unloaded. You probably don't want to unload buffers and reload them each time you navigate away/to a file. Better use an autcommand to `:update` on `BufLeave` on something like that.

Comment: Also note that it the option `autowrite` option behaves more like `:update` than `:w`, it only writes modified buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are `FocusGained` and `FocusLost` events. But read the doc to make sure it will work as you want.

In addition to those two events, there are also events like `winLeave` or `BufLeave`, which may be helpful for your auto-save needs.

Read the docs.

Comment: No. They don't work as they get fired when we change buffer. We need to somehow search the event that fires for current buffer only and on vim/neovim leave only. It should not impact other non-saved buffers.

Comment: @arpit I tested here with `BufLeave` it can be captured when we change focus from a window. I don't know your concrete requirement, what you want to do when this event occurs is another topic. You can choose which buffer/file you want to save.